# Changing CSS with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've wrote a script to change a few CSS properties of a div. I've tried 2 methods I found on google but neither of them work. I've thoroughly read the examples and I don't know why this won't work.

When there is less content in the `#rightsection` then there are images in the `#leftsection`, the `#rightsection` attaches to the bottom of the `#contentpage`. But if there is too much content in the `#rightsection`, the content overflows. So I want to change to `position:absolute` to `position:static` when there's a scroll detected upon overflow.

I'm not really that good with JQuery so I'm hoping anybody of you would know the answer. If anybody does know, I'd appreciate it.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
    }

    //Method 1
    if($("#rightsection").hasScrollBar()){
        $('.rightsection1').css({
            "position":"static",
            "margin":"-75px 0 0 150px"
        });
    }

    //Method 2
    if($("#rightsection").hasScrollBar()){
        $('#rightsection').addClass("rightsection1");
        $('#rightsection').removeClass("rightsection2");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2e1hcweq/4/)

**Solution**

I changed `(function($)` by `$(document).ready(function()` and now it works flawlessly.

Comment: `margin-top` only expects `1` value, change `margin-top` to `margin`

Comment: I checked the fiddle and saw you haven't add jQuery. Here's an updated version of the fiddle with an added jQuery lib at 1.11 http://jsfiddle.net/2e1hcweq/1/

Comment: "margin-top" value should be changed to marginTop

Comment: @AmitSoni my bad. I removed it.

Comment: @CarloGonzales I saw that too. I changed the JSFiddle link.

Comment: I added "background-color":"blue" to your method one and it works. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud I just tried it too and it doesn't work for me. Can you link a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2e1hcweq/8/

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud So at least the JQuery works, that's great. But the `position` still doesn't change.

Comment: If you inspect, you can see that the styles are applied (position and margin). That's why I ask you what are you trying to achieve, because I think your problem comes from CSS.

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud when there is less content in the `#rightsection` then there are images in the `#leftsection`, the `#rightsection` attaches to the bottom of the `#contentpage`. But if there is too much content in the `#rightsection`, the content overflows. So I want to change to `position:absolute` to `position:static` when there's a scroll detected upon overflow, with JQuery.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand what you really want to do. But I tried to change the values of the margin and tested with less content, your right section is in static position and the margin is applied. Small content : http://jsfiddle.net/2e1hcweq/9/ , large content : http://jsfiddle.net/2e1hcweq/10/

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud it works for you but not for me. I'm gonna look in to that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Vasco it's working for me in Chrome, what browser is it not working for you on? Check the F12 tools to see if the styles are being applied so you know whether it's a jquery or css issue.

Comment: @gaynorvader I'm using firefox. I can see it working in the JSFiddle, it just doesnt work when I program it in notepad++. Strange thing is, when I imported my entire mark-up and stylesheet into JSFiddle, then it worked. Really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I changed `(function($)` by `$(document).ready(function()` and now it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: you should notice that the reason it works when you changed `(function($)` by `$(document).ready(function()` is simply because the codes here are not loaded at all.

`(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` is used for [$.noConflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), in case that `$` sign is used by other libraries.

Whether you add this wrapper or not, you will always need `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` (or `$(function() { ... });` , in short hand) to initialize jQuery functions.

So in your case, you may do something like this:

```
  (function($) {
    $(function() { 
      ...
      // your codes here
      ...
    });
   })(jQuery);
```